# about c# delegate parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

Sorry it's a little dumb...

```
List<Action> ps = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var k = i;
    ps.Add(() => Console.WriteLine($"print {k}"));
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ps[i].Invoke();
}
```

// 0 1 2 ... 9

```
List<Action> ps = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ps.Add(() => Console.WriteLine($"print {i}"));
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ps[i].Invoke();
}
```

// 10 10 10 ... 10

Why do i have to pass a new variable k to make the delegate work?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938217, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742365, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732157

Comment: (Not "dumb" at all - frequently asked, but only because it does seem  counterintuitive!)

Comment: So should I treat the delegate "captured" parameters as if they were references? Just remember to use a var k. @JonSkeet

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but if you read through all those answers, you should be able to predict how any given piece of code will behave, and write code accordingly.

Comment: @Charlieface: Have never actually added more than one link to a duplicate. Doing so now... we live and learn :)

Comment: I just found there're 4 links... Thank you again! Tested the behavior using a destructor. I will carefully do some unit test from now on.